# Excel cell: extract string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column in excel containing text:

- **Database piece "Hello"."India" "Part1"**
- **external source "Welcome"."Tiger" "Part2"**
- **internal counter "Travel"."Doctor" "Part3"**

I want to extract data from above:

- **"Hello"."India"**
- **"Welcome"."Tiger"**
- **"Travel"."Doctor"**

in a column

and in 2nd column I want:

- **"Part1"**
- **"Part2"**
- **"Part3"**

Please help me to write a function in excel for this.

Comment: Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and act accordingly. So make an effort yourself first and show your script sofar. You dont have the skills to script yourself? Please learn the language (follow a training) or go to other websites where freelancers are offering their services.

Comment: @K_B: I am Sorry K_B. But I am trying to do the same, I have used MID , LEN function to solve the 1st part.
I have an logical idea to do this, but not able to implement this.

Comment: Is the logic always: `some text "ab"."cd" "ef"` ? Then you might be able to derive the parts by finding the " symbols by using the `SEARCH()` function.

Comment: Search funtion is not allowing me to find " .

Comment: Use `Search()` or `Find()`, as per the answer below by lynamc (so 4 double quotes for finding 1 double quote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part  =MID(A1,FIND("""",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND("""",A1))-FIND("""",A1))

Second part =MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(".",A1))+1,99)

The first one finds the first occurrence of a double quote and extracts to the next space and the second one finds the first space after the full stop and extracts the remainder (up to 99 characters). Consequently it is heavily dependent on the format of the source column